# swift Navigate between two view controllers

Tags: swift, navigation, uistoryboard

```
@IBAction func goView1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let view1 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1") as ViewController
}
```

gives error:

```
Value of optional type 'UIStoryboard' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' ?
```

help me please

Answer (score 0):

```
 let view1 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIentifier") as? ViewControllerName
```

This will resolve your problem

Comment: self.navigationController.presentViewController(view1, animated: true, completion: nil); there also some mistake

Answer (score 0):

This way you can Instantiate and Present a new `viewController`

```
@IBAction func goView1(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1") as! UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

For more Info check [THIS](https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/3/12/present-storyboard-view-controller-programmatically-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial) tutorial.